# How to check if button is clicked more than once in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to get a `true` if button is clicked more than once. How to do so?

Now I'm testing it like this for checking if it's clicked:

```
  var clicked = $(this).data('clicked', true);
    if (clicked) {
        return alert('button is clicked!');
    } else {
        return alert('false');
    }
```

But how to check if it's clicked more than once? Tried to change

```
 $(this).data('clicked', true);
```

to

```
$(this).data('clicked', true) > 1;
```

But obviously it didn't helped. Thanks a lot

Comment: What code do you have in the click handler?

Comment: Please show your complete code (minimal complete verifiable example), including the click handler as @/Brainfeeder said above.

Comment: use counter????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is slightly off. You're using the setter of `data()`, so `clicked` will always be the jQuery object which was selected, hence the `if` statement will always be true.

You need to separate the get from the set of `data()`. Something like this:

```js
$('.foo').click(function() {
  var $foo = $(this);
  if (!$foo.data('clicked')) {
    console.log('first click');
  } else {
    console.log('button has been clicked before');
  }
  $foo.data('clicked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="foo">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
$(function() {

    // Handle clicks on #button
    $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
        var trigger = $(this),
        clickCount = trigger.data('clickCount');

        clickCount++;

        trigger.data('clickCount', clickCount);

        if(clickCount > 1) {
            alert('This baby was clicked more than once!')
        }
        else {
            // some other code
        }
    });
});
```